# How to select information from more then one table in MySQL Database using PHP and mySQli, has to be combined single query

Tags: php, mysql

I am confused on how to query multiple tables at once and how to combine them. What is the proper why to combine multiple SELECT queries in it's simplest form?

```
$id = 2;
$result = conn()->query("

     SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$id'
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM users_meta WHERE id='$id'

");
```

**Edit** 3-5-2016

Speed tips for reading lots of data for MySqli.

- Set Storage Engine to MyISAM. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Well what is the problem with this code?

Comment: what is the expected result and what is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `join`

```
SELECT * FROM members m join users_meta u
     on m.id=u.id
     WHERE m.id='$id'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I now understand. *light bulb turns on*